# Trying to drop logs the end with certain string logstash

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I'm trying to drop the logs for 200 codes in response to Prometheus scraping. In Kibana this is the message field:

```
November 17th 2021, 12:37:01.769    10.128.8.31 - - [17/Nov/2021:12:37:01 +0000] "GET /metrics HTTP/1.1" 200 36881 "-" "Prometheus/2.25.0"
```

I've added the following to the filter in logstash config:

```
if [message] =~ /.*Prometheus\/2.25.0$/   {  
    drop { }  
  }
```

But the logs are still coming through, I've tried many variations but nothing seems to work so I'm unsure what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: The message ends with a double quote, so `/.*Prometheus\/2.25.0$/` will never match.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're ingesting Apache logs, you can try to parse the line using a pre-defined `grok` pattern and then simply drop the event based on the user-agent.

Grokking the Apache log you've shared using the `COMBINEDAPACHELOG` pattern (more patterns can be found [here](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/patterns#)) would parse the `message` field as follows:

```
{
  "clientip": [
    [
      "10.128.8.31"
    ]
  ],
  "ident": [
    [
      "-"
    ]
  ],
  "auth": [
    [
      "-"
    ]
  ],
  "timestamp": [
    [
      "17/Nov/2021:12:37:01 +0000"
    ]
  ],
  "verb": [
    [
      "GET"
    ]
  ],
  "request": [
    [
      "/metrics"
    ]
  ],
  "httpversion": [
    [
      "1.1"
    ]
  ],
  "rawrequest": [
    [
      null
    ]
  ],
  "response": [
    [
      "200"
    ]
  ],
  "bytes": [
    [
      "36881"
    ]
  ],
  "referrer": [
    [
      ""-""
    ]
  ],
  "agent": [
    [
      ""Prometheus/2.25.0""
    ]
  ]
}
```

So now all you have to do is to `drop` the event based on the value of the `agent` field:

```
filter {
  # first grok the Apache log
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG}" }
  }
  # then drop if you want to ignore a given user-agent 
  if [agent] == "Prometheus\/2.25.0" {
    drop {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting the check to drop inside the if statement where I was checking the kubernetes namespace works i.e

```
if "example-namespace" in [kubernetes][namespace] {
mutate { add_field => { "proj_index" => "example-namespace"} }                    json {
  source => "message"
} 
if [message] =~ /.*Prometheus\/2.25.0"$/ {
drop { }
  }
 }
}
```

It didn't work putting the drop conditional inside the filter but outside any particular namespace so it would apply to all of them for some reason.

Comment: You're still much better off grokking your logs as shown in my answer, instead of performing regexp on them.